# If $p$ is a prime number and $4p^4+1$ is also prime, then what is $p$?

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers

The problem:

> If $p$ is prime and $4p^4+1$ is also prime, what can the value of $p$ be?

I am sure this is a pretty simple question, but I just can't tackle it. I don't even known how I should begin...

Answer (score 5):

$$ 4 p^4 + 1 = (2 p^2 + 2p+1)(2 p^2 - 2p +1) = (2p(p+1)+1) (2p(p-1)+1)$$

Answer (score 4):

For any $n$ which is not divisible by $5$ you have that $n^4\equiv 1\pmod{5}$ then you must have $4p^4+1\equiv 4+1\equiv 0\pmod{5}$ but $4p^4+1$ must be prime what does that leave you with?

Answer (score 4):

If $p\ne 5$, then $p^4\equiv 1 \bmod 5$ by Fermat's Little Theorem. Thus $4p^4+1\equiv 0 \bmod 5$, that is $4p^4{+}1$ is divisible by $5$ and since $4p^4>2^4>5$ this is not prime.

If $p=5$ , $4p^4+1=2501$ is not prime either. So there is no such $p$.